# Firstrun message with username

Tags: node.js, botframework

Im working with botbuilder v3.9.1 (Node) and generic webchat, and I am using the next code to hail to user:

```
bot.on('conversationUpdate', function (message) {
    console.log("message: " + JSON.stringify(message));
    if (message.membersAdded) {
        message.membersAdded.forEach(function (identity) {
            if (identity.id === message.address.bot.id) {
                bot.loadSession(message.address, function (err, session) {
                    session.send("Hi");
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

It works ok, but the problem is that I would like to hail to user by his name, but until the user doesn't say anything, user is not added to conversation, and I can't access to user name information. Only when user writes a message, I get a message like this:

```
message: {"type":"conversationUpdate","membersAdded":[{"id":"default-user","name":"User"}],....
```

In emulator channel, I receive user member added as soon as I click "connect" button, but in webchat it is not working like that. Any idea about how could I resolve this problem or how are you doing it guys?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Daniel, have you tried logging the events in middleware to check who/what is being added to the conversation and when?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-intercept-messages. I haven't worked with Webchat in a while but as you've seen with the Emulator, two conversationUpdate events fire, one for the bot and one for the user. It might be the case with Webchat that the Bot Framework does not acknlowedge a user via Webchat until they send a message. In that case, I'd suggest using the Direct Line API instead.

Comment: Yes that's not the case with webchat, i'm experiencing the same as Daniel where you don't have information about the user before its first input